# How to rename ES Module export to a string literal that is not a valid identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description:%7E:text=You%20can%20rename%20a%20name%20to%20something%20that%27s%20not%20a%20valid%20identifier%20by%20using%20a%20string%20literal.),

> You can rename a name to something that's not a valid identifier by using a string literal. For example:
>
> ```
> export { myFunction as "my-function" };
> ```

However I get an error in VSCode about this code:
[image]

What's wrong and how to make this work?

I've tried importing this in another file like this:

```js
import { "my function" as func} from "./test.js";

console.log(func());
```

and run this second file with node. Surprisingly, it outputs proper `1`. Does this mean that node.js supports this syntax, but TypeScript doesn't?

- Node v16.15.0
- TypeScript compiler v4.8.4 (used for checking only, no transpilation)

Comment: why do you want to have spaces in your function name?

Comment: My use case is a bit different, I need to export something like `group-item` or `group.item`. It's for Cloud Functions for Firebase. I need grouped exports. And I know another way of achieving the goal. But here I'm trying to understand why the correct syntax according to the specification produces error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string specifiers for exports is a rather [new feature](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/2154) of ES2022.

It is implemented in engines for quite some time and supported by Babel since [v7.12](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/10/15/7.12.0#imports-and-exports-with-string-names-12091httpsgithubcombabelbabelpull12091), but not yet in TypeScript. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40594) which is currently planned for the 4.8 milestone.

Comment: Thank you very much for a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes indeed.

MDN is about JavaScript, not TypeScript.

NodeJS execute JavaScript too.

Comment: So perhaps I need to address this question to the TypeScript team. The point is that TypeScript is used as a development tool, and it disrupts the development in this case :)

Comment: Well, you asked: "Does this mean that node.js supports this syntax, but TypeScript doesn't?", I think I answered this. If you have a different question, you are welcome to ask

Comment: Sure. My comment is just a lamentation :) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Node JS doesn't execute TypeScript; you need to transpile the TS source code to JS before Node can handle it.

Comment: @Quentin, my code is in JavaScript. See my note in the question about TypeScript - it is used for type checking in VSCode only, not for transpilation.